# How to read MultipartFormDataContent from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API application that returns multiple files to the user in a `HttpResponseMessage`. Below is a sample of the `HttpResponseMessage` object

---

```
  Dim apple, banana As Byte()

  apple = File.ReadAllBytes("some place")

  banana = File.ReadAllBytes("some place")

  Dim multiDataContent As New MultipartFormDataContent()

  multiDataContent.Add(New ByteArrayContent(apple), "apple", "apple.xml")

  multiDataContent.Add(New ByteArrayContent(banana), "banana", "banana.xsd")


  Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)

  response.Content = multiDataContent

  return response
```

---

My Question is how can I read the `MultipartFormDataContent` as the object returned to the client is a `StreamContent (response.Content)`, how can I read the `MultipartFormDataContent` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/

Importantly do not forget to add System.Net.Http.Formatting to the project and "Imports System.Net.Http.Formatting" into the class so that you can use HttpContentMultipartExtensions.